# Adobe Flash plugin update needed on Linux Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, firefox, plugin

I am little confused about whether I may or not update Adobe Flash plugin for Firefox, on a Fedora 20 machine.

Every time I try to see, let's say a YouTube video, I get a warning message about my Flash plugin being outdated and a potential danger.

My current config is

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum info  flash-plugin
Plugin abilitati:refresh-packagekit
Pacchetti installati
Nome         : flash-plugin
Arch         : i386
Versione     : 11.2.202.400
Rilascio     : release
Dimensione   : 18 M
Repo         : installed
Sommario     : Adobe Flash Player 11.2
URL          : http://www.adobe.com/downloads/
Licenza      : Commercial
Descrizione  : Adobe Flash Plugin 11.2.202.400 Fully Supported: Mozilla SeaMonkey 1.0+, Firefox 1.5+, Mozilla 1.7.13+
```

And Firefox seems to be up to date:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum info firefox
Plugin abilitati:refresh-packagekit
Pacchetti installati
Nome         : firefox
Arch         : i686
Versione     : 38.0
Rilascio     : 4.fc20
Dimensione   : 115 M
Repo         : installed
Dal repo     : updates
Sommario     : Mozilla Firefox Web browser
URL          : http://www.mozilla.org/projects/firefox/
Licenza      : MPLv1.1 or GPLv2+ or LGPLv2+
Descrizione  : Mozilla Firefox è un browser web open-source, creato nel rispetto degl : standard, massimizzando performance e portabilità.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: We don't use `SOLVED` tags to indicate answered questions here. Instead, you may want to post the solution (possibly including what led you up to it) as a self-answer, and accept that answer. That will indicate to the community that the question has been resolved to your satisfaction, while clearly separating the question from the answer.

Comment: Yes, please post an answer with your solution, that will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I upgraded to Linux `fedora-pc 4.4.9-300.fc23.x86_64`, I tried the following instruction:

```
yum update firefox
yum -y remove  flash-plugin --nogpgcheck
yum clean all
yum remove  adobe-release
rpm -ivh http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-i386-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
yum install flash-plugin
yum info flash-plugin

Plugin abilitati:refresh-packagekit
Pacchetti installati
Nome         : flash-plugin
Arch         : i386
Versione     : 11.2.202.466
Rilascio     : release
Dimensione   : 18 M
Repo         : installed
Dal repo     : adobe-linux-i386
Sommario     : Adobe Flash Player 11.2
URL          : http://www.adobe.com/downloads/
Licenza      : Commercial
Descrizione  : Adobe Flash Plugin 11.2.202.466  : Fully Supported: Mozilla SeaMonkey 1.0+, Firefox 1.5+, Mozilla 1.7.13+
```

Reference of the commands at point 6 on [this site](http://www.binarytides.com/better-fedora-23/).

Comment: Since I upgraded to Linux fedora-pc 4.4.9-300.fc23.x86_64, I am following istructions from [here, see point 6](http://www.binarytides.com/better-fedora-23/) .